Нужен ли nginx, если приложение работает в podman?
Имеет ли смысл устанавливать на сервер nginx, если приложение работает в podman-compose? И если да, то может лучше его закинуть в контейнер того podman-compose и от него прокинуть на внешку порт на 443?

Nginx вам понадобится, для использования нескольких приложений с одной точкой входа. reverse proxy
